# TypeError: Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid. Use `data.to_timestamp()` instead

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How can I convert a `date` column with format of `2014-09` to format of `2014-09-01 00:00:00.000`? The previous format is converted from `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('M')`.

I use `df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000')`, but it generates an error: `TypeError: Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid.  Use data.to_timestamp() instead`. I also try with `pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')`, it generates same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First idea is convert periods to timestamps by [`Series.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_timestamp.html) and then use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
print (df)
      date
0  2014-09

print (df.dtypes)
date    period[M]
dtype: object

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.to_timestamp('s').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000')
print (df)
                      date
0  2014-09-01 00:00:00.000
```

Or simply add last values same for each value:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.to_timestamp('s').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').add('.000')
print (df)
                      date
0  2014-09-01 00:00:00.000
```

Or:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m').add('-01 00:00:00.000')
print (df)
                      date
0  2014-09-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

use `%f` for milliseconds

```
df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

sample code is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2014-09-01 00:00:00.000']
})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df
```

which gives you the following output

```
    Date
0   2014-09-01
```

#### to convert `2014-09` in Period to `2014-09-01 00:00:00.000`, we can do as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2014-09-05']
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period("M")
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-01 00:00:00.000')
df
```

Comment: This will generates six `0`s in the end, but I only need three of them.

Comment: Did you try with `2014-01` format date? I just tried with your code, it generates `TypeError: Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid.  Use `data.to_timestamp()` instead`. I use Python3.

Comment: Please note I need to convert `2014-09` to `2014-09-01 00:00:00.000`

Answer (score 1):

Try stripping the last 3 digits

```
print(pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[0][:-3])
```

Output:

```
2014-09-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: With `2014-09-01` format, your method works very well, otherwise, I think it need to convert `timestamp` firstly as jezrael's solution. May I ask, what `[0]` stands for?

Comment: It's the first element of the series

Answer (score 1):

In the event the other answers don't work, you could try

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date).to_period('s')
df.index
```

Which should show the datetimeindex object with the frequency set as 's'